# CloudHub Deployment 502 Bad Gateway We couldn't find any Cloudhub application listening on this API

Tags: mulesoft

I have mule application version 3.8.5, when I am running studio its deployed successfully. Then I created a zip package using mvn package command then the package is deployed successfully in cloud hub space, when I accessing the application URL I am getting the following error in the browser "502 Bad Gateway We couldn't find any Cloudhub application listening on this API"

Please find the HTTP_Listener_Configuration here

```
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration">

    </http:listener-config>
    <http:request-config name="app1" protocol="${app1.protocol}" host="${app1.host}" port="${app1.port}" basePath="/center" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
        <http:basic-authentication username="${app1.username}" password="${app1.password}" preemptive="true"/>
        <tls:context enabledProtocols="TLSv1.2">
            <tls:trust-store path="truststore.ts" password="mule" type="jks" insecure="true"/>
        </tls:context>
    </http:request-config>
    <flow name="configurationsFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/center" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="welocme" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <response>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </response>
    </flow>
```

please let me know if anything is requried.

Comment: What URL are using to make the HTTP request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the HTTP Listener is listening on port 8081 but it is configured for HTTPS. CloudHub load balancer expects it to listen in port 8082 for HTTPS. It is better for CloudHub to use the predefined property ${https.port}. For local deployments in Mule 3 you will need to define it in mule-app.properties to work. CloudHub will override it.

Comment: You mean like this <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="${https.port}"
doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" protocol="HTTPS">

Comment: HI Aled, i updated configuration.xml file, as you said, but in mule-app.properties which how to set the property for localhost access in the browser? Can you please help me again that would really helpful.

Comment: The URL to run it locally should be https://localhost:8082/... asumming that you changed the port to 8082 as I suggested, or replaced it by the property and defined https.port=8082 in mule-app.properties

Comment: Hi Aled, I have updated the above changes, now I am going to start the deployment

Comment: Hi Aled still i am not able to access the cloud hub url after the deployment https://today.us-e2.cloudhub.io/center/8082 (No listener for endpoint:/center/8082)

Comment: i added my configuration.xml file in the above.

Comment: CloudHub load balancer maps 8082 to 443 for HTTPS, which is the default that browsers use, so you don't need to specify it. Try https://today.us-e2.cloudhub.io/center/ (without the port).

Comment: if I use only domain URL i am getting the error "No listener for endpoint: https://today.us-e2.cloudhub.io/center"

Comment: That means that your application received the request in the right port, which was the objective of your original question. It just wasn't listening to `/center`. Is it possible that the flow wasn't updated with the HTTP listener when you tested?

Comment: Hi Aled, As you said i have added HTTP listener connector to get access other application details from the backend now i can get message from the payload whichever I have written as a string, thank you so much for the new middleware learning from you.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the https  "s" from the url  and it was worked
I mean http://

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).